# What happened to Martin Chaplin's famous Water Structure and Science website?

Tags: discussion, resources

[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/74995/16035) and likely numerous others have drawn from (and also linked to) to London South Bank University Emeritus Professor [Martin Chaplin](https://www.lsbu.ac.uk/about-us/people/people-finder/prof-martin-chaplin#id_sixth)'s website:

> Water Structure and Science, where he presents a topical review of the literature concerning water and presents explanations for water’s strange but important properties.

All the links to that page seem to have gone dead. Is this important and encyclopedic resource now unavailable?

Comment: I was advised that this was better to ask in meta than the main site.

Comment: Questions like this are better suited for chat. Availability of third-party resources is outside the scope of Meta, which is devoted to the discussions about Chemistry.SE.

Comment: @andselisk Technically it is about a chem SE post so I think meta is ok. In any case, it probably shouldn’t be on main site. :-)

Comment: @orthocresol I agree this question doesn't hurt anyone and chosen between the main site and Meta, Meta sure is a better choice, but the aforementioned relation is such a stretch IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The website and many (if not all) of its subpages should be accessible via the [Wayback Machine (archive.org)](https://archive.org/). Simply enter the desired page into the search bar and pick a relevant snapshot of the page.

The linked answer points to the vibrational spectrum of water. The [original link](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_vibrational_spectrum.html) is dead, but the most recent snapshot (Nov 2020) is accessible [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111195918/http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_vibrational_spectrum.html) and seems to be quite a faithful reproduction: for example, it has all the images attached in the answer.

(This is a very general tool which can be used to fix broken links or find information that has otherwise gone missing.)